# Can you get trace output from a process that was started within another application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running an app A and it starts another app B using process start. Is it possible for me to get the trace information of app B?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture StandardOutput. From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx):

```
// Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

So by reading `StandardOutput` (and/or `StandardError`) you can capture the output of a process you just launched.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Though I was getting the Console.WriteLine, I am not able to extract the Trace.WriteLine information.  I'm not sure if it's possible.